# Setting the line number to a variable in Emacs

Tags: elisp

I am trying to set the current line number to a variable in Elisp but keep getting a void-variable error!

The code is:

(setq x what-line)

I'd also like to set the total number of lines in the buffer to a variable as well, but get the same error?!

Comment: It just a syntax error. Wrap `what-line` in parenthesis, as it is a function not a variable.

Comment: `(what-line)` returns `Line 96` not `96`... which makes it great for a minibuffer display.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(setq x (line-number-at-pos)
      y (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))
```

How to find out about this kind of thing? Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `what-line` <kbd>RET</kbd> to see the source code of `what-line`. Reading `simple.el` (the file in which `what-line` is defined) is a good way to get familiar with elementary Elisp programming.

Comment: Depending on your version of Emacs, this function might not be available. You can approximate it largely with this snippet of code: `(1+ (count-lines 1 (point)))`

Answer (score 3):

```
(setq x (what-line))
```

Comment: This good for display, but not for a pure number.. It outputs `Line 54`.. which is great for what I sometimes want, so +1. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The line-number-at-pos function mentioned in a previous answer only considers the accessible portion of the buffer.  If the buffer is "narrowed" it won't count the hidden lines, so this can be rather confusing.

If you read the code for the what-line function you can see how it deals with narrowed buffers (indeed what-line works by calling line-number-at-pos).